# Proving elementary properties of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and $U \subset V$ a subspace.
>
> (a) Show that the additive identity $0$ is contained in $U$.
>
> (b) Suppose that $u$ is an element of $U$. Show that its additive inverse $-u$ is also an element of $U$.
>
> (c) Use parts (a) and (b) to show that $U$ is a vector space over $F$.

Parts (a) and (b) leave me a bit baffled. I thought (a) was the definition of a subspace, but perhaps the author of this problem intended to use the definition that a subspace is a nonempty subset of $V$ which is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

I'd want to then proceed as follows. $U$ is nonempty, so there exists $u \in U$. Then $(-1)u \in U$ because it is closed under multiplication. I know that, in a vector space $V$, that $(-1)u = -u$, but $U$ is not a vector space. But $u$ and $(-1)u$ are certainly elements of the larger vector space $V$. Can I assert that equality in $V$ implies equality in $U$? So $(-1)u = -u$ in $U$ because it is true in $V$, and because $u + (-u) = 0$ in $V$, we also have $u + (-u) = 0$ in $U$. As $U$ is closed under addition, it contains $0$.

Something leads me to think I did that incorrectly because I had to prove (b) in order to solve (a).

Am I missing something, or is there an alternative approach I could use to solve this problem in the intended way?

Comment: You can just multiply $u$ with $0$. This immediately gives $0\in U$.

Comment: @Andijvie  I proved that $0u = 0$ in a vector space, but does the result also hold for elements in the subspace? This may be obvious, but it's also confusing me since the proof of that required the vector space axioms which I don't yet have.

Comment: elements in the subspace are also elements of the bigger space - which is a vector space by assumption.

Comment: I cannot understand part (c): $V$ is given to be an $F$-space.

Comment: I think that to answer this question one needs to  know precisely how your book defines a vector space, and how it defines a subspace. For myself I always insist that $U$ being a subspace means that the operations of $V$ restrict to give operations of $U$, and so (a) and (b) are automatic.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Sorry, this was a typo on my part. Part (c) should have said: prove that $U$ is a vector space over $F$. I believe the definition is: a nonempty subset that is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.